# graphql query not uploading form values to the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have a code written to take reviews and store them in graphcms using graphql but I keep getting the error below

```
: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"input:3: Field \"createReview\" of type \"Review\" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean \"createReview { ... }\"?\n"}],"data":null,"extensions":{"requestId":"cl5il6xdsgfz10cugslzaczhb"},"status":400,"headers":{}},"request":{"query":"\n    mutation CreateReview($name: String!, $email: String!, $testimonial: String!){\n      createReview(data: {name: $name, email: $email, testimonial: $testimonial})\n    }\n  ","variables":{"name":"Favour","email":"mikkylipsy@gmail.com","testimonial":"I love the hell out of favourite tech solutions"}}}
    at /home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:359:31
    at step (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:63:23)
    at Object.next (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:44:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/kimmoramicky/Desktop/fts_portfolio/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:35:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  response: {
    errors: [ [Object] ],
    data: null,
    extensions: { requestId: 'cl5il6xdsgfz10cugslzaczhb' },
    status: 400,
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] }
  },
  request: {
    query: '\n' +
      '    mutation CreateReview($name: String!, $email: String!, $testimonial: String!){\n' +
      '      createReview(data: {name: $name, email: $email, testimonial: $testimonial})\n' +
      '    }\n' +
      '  ',
    variables: {
      name: 'Favour',
      email: 'mikkylipsy@gmail.com',
      testimonial: 'I love the hell out of favourite tech solutions'
    }
  }
}
```

The program is meant to take in a user reviews or testimonial and save it in the database using graphql but so far, I keep getting the error above the moment I click on **post review**

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong with the following code below:

api/reviews.js

```
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request"

const graphqlAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT
const graphcmsToken = process.env.GRAPHCMS_TOKEN

export default async function comments(req, res){
  const {name, email, slug, testimonial} = req.body

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(graphqlAPI, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${graphcmsToken}`
    }
  })

  const query = gql`
    mutation CreateReview($name: String!, $email: String!, $testimonial: String!){
      createReview(data: {name: $name, email: $email, testimonial: $testimonial})
    }
  `

  try{
    const result = await graphQLClient.request(query, req.body)
    return res.status(200).send(result)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).send(error)
  }

}
```

services/index.js

```
export const submitReviews = async (obj) =>{
    const result = await fetch('/api/reviews', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    })

    return result.json()
}
```

components/reviewForm.jsx

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReviewPopup from './ReviewPopup'
import {submitReviews} from '../services'

const ReviewForm = () => {
  const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopup] = useState(false)

  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  const [localStorage, setLocalStorage] = useState(null)
  const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false)
  const testimonialEl = useRef()
  const nameEl = useRef()
  const emailEl = useRef()

  const handletestimonialSubmission = () => {
    setError(false)

    const {value: testimonial} = testimonialEl.current
    const {value: name} = nameEl.current
    const {value: email} = emailEl.current

    if(!testimonial || !name || !email ){
      setError(true)
      return
    }

    const testimonialObj = {name, email, testimonial}

    submitReviews(testimonialObj)
      .then((res) =>{
        setShowSuccessMessage(true)
        setTimeout(()=>{
          setShowSuccessMessage(false)
        }, 3000)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
              <span onClick={() => setButtonPopup(true)} className="transition duration-500 transform hover:-translate-y-1 inline-block outline outline-offset-2 outline-[#001973] text-lg font-meduim rounded text-[#001973] px-4 py-3 cursor-pointer">
                  Write a review
              </span>
              <ReviewPopup trigger={buttonPopup} setTrigger={setButtonPopup}>
                <h3 className="text-xl mb-8 font-semibold border-b pb-4">We are happy to hear from you!</h3>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 mb-4">
                <input 
                  type="text"
                  className ="py-2 px-4 outline-none w-full rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 bg-gray-100 text-gray-700"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  name="name"
                  ref={nameEl}
                />
                <input 
                  type="text"
                  className ="py-2 px-4 outline-none w-full rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 bg-gray-100 text-gray-700"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="email"
                  ref={emailEl}
                />
                <textarea
                  name="testimonial" 
                  // id="" cols="30" rows="10"
                  placeholder="Leave a review..."
                  ref={testimonialEl} 
                  className="p-4 outline-none w-full rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 bg-gray-100 text-gray-700">
                </textarea>
                {error && <p className="text-xs text-red-500">All fields are required.</p>}
                <div className="mt-8">
                  <button 
                    className="transition duration-500 ease hover:bg-[#001973] hover:text-white inline-block outline outline-offset-2 outline-[#001973] text-xl rounded text-[#001973] p-2 cursor-pointer"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={handletestimonialSubmission}
                    >Post Review</button>
                    {showSuccessMessage && <span className="text-xl float-right font-semibold mt-3 text-green-500">testimonial submitted for review</span>}
                </div>
                </div>
              </ReviewPopup>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReviewForm
```

Comment: You need to address the error it's giving you - `Field \"createReview\" of type \"Review\" must have a selection of subfields`.  Add subfields to `createReview`

Comment: @larz Please can you tell how I should add subfields to createReview